# pyspark backfill nulls using only the last value in the partition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to fill nulls in a column based on the last value of a partition (this is guaranteed not to be null). There could be non null values in between which have to be retained. Only the nulls need to be filled. I tried using the 'last' function but it overwrites the non null values in between as well.

eg.:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| grp1 | null |
| grp1 | 4 |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp2 | null |
| grp2 | 6 |
| grp2 | null |
| grp2 | 7 |

Required output:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp1 | 4 |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp2 | 7 |
| grp2 | 6 |
| grp2 | 7 |
| grp2 | 7 |

What I am getting instead:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp1 | 5 |
| grp2 | 7 |
| grp2 | 7 |
| grp2 | 7 |
| grp2 | 7 |

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
fill_window_spec = (
            Window.partitionBy(partition_column_list)
            .orderBy(col(order_by_column))
            .rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize)
        )
filled_df = input_df.withColumn(f"""Filled{fill_column}""",last(col(fill_column), True).over(fill_window_spec))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html)/[`otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise.html) functions to run the last "expression" only when the column is null, like this:

```py
fill_window_spec = (
    Window.partitionBy(["id"])
    .orderBy(F.col("val"))
    .rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
filled_df = df.withColumn(
    "filled",
    F.when(
        F.col("val").isNull(),
        F.last(F.col("val"), True).over(fill_window_spec),
    ).otherwise(F.col("val")),
)
```

Also you can use [`Window.unboundedFollowing`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.unboundedFollowing.html) instead of `sys.maxsize`.